# Laravel 7 php artisan migrate database error

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, php-7.4

When I run 'php artisan migrate' i am getting the following error

```
 Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = dbname_main and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

I have tried removing the vendor and reinstalling but no success. I am using php7.4

Is all the php extensions required for laravel 7.x is available for php7.4?

Comment: If you are down voting, it will be helpful if you please specify the reason for the down vote. Also I have checked the database parameters in the env file. it is not the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you get this error with invalid db credentials.
Try using the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the values that you set for your database variables (those prefixed with DB_) in your **.env** file

Answer (score -1):

If you're sure your db credentials are correct, try:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```